# Running and accessing multiple angular applications

Tags: angularjs, typescript, webpack, microservices

I am a newbie to Angular and was trying to see if we can access another application(hosted on different port, has a completely different repository and Angular version). 
Lets say I have two Angular Typescript projects , A and B.

```
=======================================
Project A configuration: 
Angular 1.5
Typescript 2
Grunt for build purposes.
runs on localhost:8080 

=======================================
Project B configuration: 
Angular 2
Typescript 2
Webpack for build purposes.
runs on localhost:9000
=======================================
```

Each of theses apps, A and B are hosted on different repositories. 
Now, lets say project A is master and has a tab(button) in it which on click should call the index page hosted on project B.

The button label is 'microapp; and below is the src :

```
$scope.showMicroApp = function showMicroAppView(isMessagePanelOpen) {
           // $scope.isEnvelopeOpen = !!isMessagePanelOpen;
            $scope.changeRoute('/microapp');
            $location.path('/microapp'); // HOW DO I REDIRECT?
        };
```

Why am I doing this ?

I am doing this to achieve independence in the front end part of my project. 
Such that if I change a particular screen/module, I don't have to build the entire project. I can simply build the changed module and see the changes reflected. 
Is this achievable ? Do I need to change the existing implementation of the project B?

Kindly help if you have any leads.

Answer (score 2):

Since you have hosted your Applications A and B as separately, you should have to navigate to absolute path instead of relative.

You no need to build both the application modules. Only build the modules that are changed because both are hosted separately on your web server and it will work independently.

[image]

I hope this information will helps